# How to use TopPercent and TopCount in CalculatedMemebers?

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is it possible to use TopPercent or TopCount in CalculatedMembers in a MDX query?

Comment: AFAIK Yes, calculated members does not have this kind of limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's basically no limitation in calculated member formula. But if your question is about having a calculated member of type 'set', then you should use a SET instead (WITH SET ...) or if you're using [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) a function (WITH [FUNCTION](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Declared%20Functions.html)...)

Cheers.

Comment: currently, I want to use direct set functions such as TopPercent, CrossJoin directly in CalculatedMember without using it inside Sum() or Count() like functions. Will that be possible?

Comment: In that case that should be a 'dynamic' set: WITH SET myItems AS TopPercent( ... ). A calculated member value cannot be a set.